# WP_Query and two custom fields returns no posts

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-field

Having trouble with WP_Query returning no posts when filtering on two custom fields, although testing for each custom field individually works perfectly. After reviewing documentation for [custom field parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) I'm obviously still missing something. Thank you in advance for any assistance or ideas.

Query that produces no posts:

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
'post_type'=>'games',
'orderby'=>'menu_order',
'order'=>'asc',
'posts_per_page' => 1,
'meta_query'=> array(
    'relation'=>'AND',
    array(
        'key'=>'game_date_time',
        'value'=>$nowtoday,
        'compare' =>'>'
    ),
    array(
        'key'=>'home_team',
        'value'=>'Allen',
        'compare'=>'LIKE'  
    )
)
));
```

SQL produced:

```
 `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id) WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'games' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') AND ( (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'game_date_time' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) > '3/5/2014 23:12') AND (mt1.meta_key = 'home_team' AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%Allen%') ) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.menu_order asc LIMIT 0, 1`
```

The var `$nowtoday` is a formatted timestamp for comparing against the custom field `game_date_time`. Querying only on `game_date_time` yields the expected result.  Here is that query and it returns the next chronological game (home or away) as intended.

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
'post_type'=>'games',
'orderby'=>'menu_order',
'order'=>'asc',
'posts_per_page' => 1,
'meta_query'=> array(
    'relation'=>'AND',
    array(
        'key'=>'game_date_time',
        'value'=>$nowtoday,
        'compare' =>'>'
    ),
    array(
       /* 'key'=>'home_team',
        'value'=>'Allen',
        'compare'=>'LIKE'  */
    )
)
));
```

SQL produced:

```
`SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'games' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') AND ( (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'game_date_time' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) > '3/5/2014 23:11') ) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.menu_order asc LIMIT 0, 1`
```

Similarly, the modified query to return only home games, that is to say, where home_game is LIKE 'Allen', returns the expected result.

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
'post_type'=>'games',
'orderby'=>'menu_order',
'order'=>'asc',
'posts_per_page' => 1,
'meta_query'=> array(
    'relation'=>'AND',
    array(
       /*  'key'=>'game_date_time',
        'value'=>$nowtoday,
        'compare' =>'>'  */
    ),
    array(
       'key'=>'home_team',
        'value'=>'Allen',
        'compare'=>'LIKE'  
    )
)
));
```

SQL produced:

```
`SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'games' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') AND ( (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'home_team' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%Allen%') ) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.menu_order asc LIMIT 0, 1`
```

The puzzle is why the two filters together produce no result, when there are numerous posts that meet both conditions, `game_date_time > $nowtoday  AND  home_team LIKE 'Allen'`.

Thank you for your time and any suggestions toward a solution!

Comment: Look at the SQL generated for each query, `echo $query->request` after each and compare them.

Comment: You can edit your question and add that output so we can have a look at it.

Comment: Generated SQL for each query added.

Comment: I don't think any of those queries are technically giving you correct results, and it has to do with your date format. `3/5/2014 23:11` is not a format MySQL understands. if you get correct results in some cases, it's accidental. you need to store it in a format like `2014/03/05 23:11`. in your current format, April 5 2013 would be greater than March 5 2014, because from a numerical perspective 452013 > 352014.

Comment: Milo you were absolutely right. Simply reformatting the date in the DB, adjusting the format of my date test to match and the double meta query produces the expected results.  If you are interested in posting your comment as an answer I will gladly give you the credit you deserve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first query gives the expected results when the date format was corrected.

`$query = new WP_Query(array(
'post_type'=>'games',
'orderby'=>'menu_order',
'order'=>'asc',
'posts_per_page' => 1,
'meta_query'=> array(
    'relation'=>'AND',
    array(
        'key'=>'game_date_time',
        'value'=>$nowtoday,
        'compare' =>'>'
    ),
    array(
        'key'=>'home_team',
        'value'=>'Allen',
        'compare'=>'LIKE'

    )
)
));`